# Delete digits after two decimal point not round number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I have this :

```
i=4.568;
document.write(i.toFixed(2));
```

output :

```
4.57
```

But i don't want to round the last number to 7 , what can i do?

Comment: When you're working with binary floating point, things like this can happen.

Comment: @Pointy: No; he just doesn't want rounding.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that in general when dealing with floating point you can't guarantee that a constant you type in will end up being what you think it is, rounding or no rounding, primarily because 2 and 5 are relatively prime :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use simple math instead;

```
document.write(Math.floor(i * 100) / 100);
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/eTTjF/2/)

You can stick it in your own function for reuse;

```
function myToFixed(i, digits) {
    var pow = Math.pow(10, digits);

    return Math.floor(i * pow) / pow;
}

document.write(myToFixed(i, 2));
```

[(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/eTTjF/1/)

Comment: The function returns nothing ..!

Comment: should be : document.write(Math.floor(i * 100)/ 100);

Comment: This is not a correct method due to floating point number precision problem. Ex: try 0.29, you will get 0.28 instead

Answer (score 9):

Just cut the longer string:

```
i.toFixed(3).replace(/\.(\d\d)\d?$/, '.$1')
```

Comment: toFixed is a shorter solution which does its job.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly convoluted approach:

```
var i=4.568,
    iToString = ​i + '';
    i = parseFloat(iToString.match(/\d+\.\d{2}/));
console.log(i);
```

This effectively takes the variable `i` and converts it to a string, and then uses a regex to match the numbers before the decimal point and the two following that decimal point, using `parseFloat()` to then convert it back to a number.

References:

- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).